# List key vaults associated with AD user accounts?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, active-directory, azure-keyvault

I'm creating a web app in MVC c# where you can login using your AD account and read secrets. The problem is that there are lots of Key Vaults - each with specific permissions. I've managed to do this with one particular vault and list the secrets in the vault using the vault URL using an AD login.

I would like to be able to list the vaults that the user has access too. I understand this is very easy to do in Powershell but I cannot find out how to do this in C#.

Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: well, you can call powershell or rest endpoints directly?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'associated'?  Do you mean the account that created the vault, the accounts that can admin the vault, the accounts that have some particular access to the account, or something else?

Comment: All members. So if the user can write to it, read it, admin it - as long as they can see the vault. I can't use powershell as it's a web app. The way I'm looking into is via the rest API but it can only show vaults associated with subscriptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no such REST we can get all the key vaults across the different subscription at present.

As a workaround, we need to list Key Vault under all the subscriptions and resource group. And check the `accessPolicies` to see whether the Key Vault is accessible.

For example an `accessPolicie` likes below, we can check whether users' object match the `objectId` in `accessPolicie`.

```
  {
    "tenantId": "",
    "objectId": "",
    "permissions": {
      "keys": [],
      "secrets": [
        "Get"
      ],
      "certificates": []
    }
  },
```

To list Key Vault under all the subscriptions and resource group you can refer the REST below:

```
GET: https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults?api-version=2015-06-01    

authorization: bearer {access_token}
```

And if you have any idea or feedback about Azure, you can submit them from [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback).

Comment: Great idea! I'll do that.